# google_apps_scripts 2 projects in 1 spreadsheet, call a function in another project

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that contains two projects. Call them P1 and P2.
There is a function in project P1, that we will cal F1.

I have a function F2, in P2 that is trying to call F1. I receive an 
error message that F1 is not defined.

code (in P2):

```
function F2()
{
   var rc = F1();
   Browser.msgBox("returned value: "+ rc);
}
```

Code (in P1):

```
function F1()
{
   return "this is a test";
}
```

Both projects are contained in the same spreadsheet file.

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible for function to be visible across projects. You can only make your functions visible across multiple files in a single project.

To meet your requirement, consider using Libraries ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries )

Comment: Then why do you have the possibility of multiple projects within the same spreadsheet file? Is a spreadsheet file just a container to collect script projects? Can I define the same project in a different spreadsheet file and have all of the same files and functions available in that file without having to copy them from the old file? What is the point of multiple projects in multiple spreadsheet files?

Comment: Multiple projects are clearly for different independent things you might want to do with Spreadsheets.

Please have a look at the libraries documentation for answers to your question.

Comment: @Srik : I do agree with you, your answer was the good one. Seems like this 'just.a.guy'user is getting used to tag his own answers as 'best' ;-/